# Xml is not Working when change the place of textview in linear layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have a working android app which has a page that uses this xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/Rapor"

        />
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="blabla"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
     android:id="@+id/blabla"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="blaa"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/blaa"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rapor"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/Report"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is the following. Right now my textview is on top of three buttons. I want to show this textview below the buttons. But when I cut the textview part and paste it after the third(last)button my app crashes. How can I put my textview below the buttons and why does my program crash?

Comment: means you want to put `TextView` below the `3` `Button` ??

Comment: yes it means that. But when I do that program crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blabla"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/blabla"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blaa"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/blaa"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rapor"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/Report"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/Rapor"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Or Use this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blabla"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/blabla"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blaa"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/blabla"
        android:id="@+id/blaa"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rapor"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/blaa"
        android:id="@+id/Report"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Report"
        android:id="@+id/Rapor"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: This is the strange thing and the thing I was asking. This has to work but it does not work in my project. You just cut the textView part and paste it to the below just like I did but it did not work on me

Comment: @FelipeHield wait I replace with `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: It worked now so I am gonna accept that as an answer. But I tried this billion times and it was failing everytime. This is so strange

Comment: @FelipeHield glad to help you.